# When to Add to Gemfile and when to just install via CLI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm just getting started with rails and I'm a little confused reading through different documentation as to when you should add the gem to your gemfile and when you should just "gem install XXX"

For example, when installing rspec and guard-rspec. I see that some folks will:

gem install rb-fsevent

and some people put it in their gemfile and bundle.

Which is the right way and how do you know which to choose? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All gems you will use in your application you should put into Gemfile.

All gems that will be just serving your application you'd better keep out of Gemfile.

For example. You need `paperclip` and `mysql2` gems to store pictures and data, so put them into Gemfile. And you need `magic_encoding` gem to do some helpful stuff. But as far you are creating it straight from console, you don't need it in your application. Keep it separate from your app.

You use test frameworks when writing code, so put them into your Gemfile.

You use `passenger` gem to deploy your apps, but you never need to use it right in your code - don't put it into Gemfile.

Answer (score 3):

The Gemfile records and manages all the *dependencies* for the application. When you list gems in the Gemfile, bundler sorts out any version conflicts and makes sure that the correct version of the gems are used with your application.

When you set up the application in a new environment (such as when your colleagues pull your changes from version control or when you deploy to a production web server), Bundler can use the gem file to ensure that the environment is set-up exactly as you had it in development.

So, anything on which your application depends (any code you call from your application for example), needs to be in the Gemfile. This includes libraries that you use for testing (although they can be excluded from the production environment).

Gems that are not dependancies of your application don't need to go in the Gemfile. An example would be `guard` which is more of a development tool than an application dependancy. You can install those with the `gem` command.

Typically though, most things you're going to want to install probably need to be in the Gemfile.

It doesn't matter if you install it with the `gem` command however. You can still put it in your Gemfile afterwards and Bundler will work out what to do.